# How to write logging messages to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, file-handling, file-writing

I am trying to use the Python `logging` library. Instead of printing the messages in the console, I want to write them to a file. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) , I'm a little unsure of how to do this. First I imported the `logging` in and then I created my logging object. Note: I am a little unsure of the `name` parameter when doing this. Is this suppose to be a filename that has a full filepath? A random name that I just make up?

```
foldname = "chk_logs"
logFileName = os.path.join(path.abspath(path.curdir),foldname + "\\Fields_Log_" + timeStamp + ".txt")             #logging
if os.path.isdir(foldname)==False:
    os.mkdir(foldname)
logFile = open(logFileName, "w")

format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(fileName=logFile, format=format, level=10)
logger = logging.getLogger('name')
```

So, suppose I want to write a message to the `logFile` from my `logger`.

```
   logger.debug("Test")
```

This essentially does nothing, even after I use `logFile.close()`. If I try this:

```
logFile.write(str(logger.debug("Test")))
```

it basically write 'None' in the `.txt` file. There must be a simple way to do this; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `fileName=logFileName` and don't handle the file yourself. `logger.debug("Test")` will write to log file, no need to do anything besides that. BTW `logger.{debug,info,warning,error}` methods don't return, that's why you see `None` in file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some boilerplate code I always use for Python logging. This is for Windows. If you're using UNIX you'll need to change the forward slashes to backslashes

```
import os
import logging
import datetime as dt
import time

LOG_FILE = os.getcwd() + "/logs"
if not os.path.exists(LOG_FILE):
    os.makedirs(LOG_FILE)
LOG_FILE = LOG_FILE + "/" + dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y_%m_%d %H_%M_%S') + ".log"
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(processName)s %(message)s")
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}".format(LOG_FILE))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logging.info("testing out the logging functionality")
```

You should end up with a log file that has a date timestamp

Comment: This totally worked. I don't quite understand why my code didn't work. Is it because you have to have a `fileHandler`? Did using `'name'` screw things up? Does it matter that I use `.txt` instead of `.log`? I'm still confused, but your solution works in my code.